# Renumbering cloned divs when one cloned div is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm working on this form (test) creator where a div containing form elements is cloned using jQuery to create more questions. The original div is hidden. each div also has a button within it that has `onClick="javascript:$(this).parent().empty().remove();"` attached. My problem is the divs are numbered question1, question 2 etc by checking how many divs with the class `question` exists and then appending that number to 'question' and setting question1(or question2, question3 etc) as the id for the cloned div- Since the original div is hidden there is no need to +1 to the number of divs with that class. But when one if the divs is deleted the numbering gets messed up. Example:
1. Div is added.
2. Div is called Question 1(id=question1) 
3. Another div is added.
4. Div is called Question 2(id=question2)
5.First Div is removed.
6.Another div is added.
7.New div is called Question 2(id=question2)
8.Question 2(id=question2) already exists since the second div was not deleted.
I need to renumber the divs when one of them is deleted.
Here's the code for cloning the divs:

```
function copyAppendQ() {
  question = document.getElementById("question");
  clone=question.cloneNode(true);
  numberOfQuestions = $('.question').length;
  id = "questioncon"+(numberOfQuestions);
  clone.id=id;
  question.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
  inid= "question"+(numberOfQuestions);
  optionid= "optionsdiv"+(numberOfQuestions);
  $('#'+id+' '+'.'+'questionin').attr('id', inid);
  $('#'+id+' '+'.'+'options').attr('id', optionid);
 $('#' + id + ' h2').html( 'Question ' + numberOfQuestions );
}
```

and the div (this div is hidden but is cloned with a different id, removing the `display:none` property set on the original div, when the above function is called)

```
<div id="question" class="question">
                <h2></h2>
                <input id="questionin" class="questionin" style="width:341px;" ><input type="button" id="remq" onClick="javascript:$(this).parent().empty().remove();" style="background-color:#E12E1E;border:0;width:120px;color:#fff;" value="Remove Question">
                <h3>Options</h3>
                <div class="options">
                <label>a.</label><input class="option optiona"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentNode.id, this.className)" type="radio" class="a" name="answer">&nbsp;
                <label>b.</label><input class="option optionb"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentNode.id, this.className)" type="radio" class="b" name="answer">
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <label>c.</label><input class="option optionc"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentNode.id, this.className)" type="radio" class="c" name="answer">&nbsp;
                <label>d.</label><input class="option optiond"><input onClick="setAnswer(this.parentNode.id, this.className)" type="radio" class="d" name="answer">
                </div>  
                </div>
```

This can be seen live here:http://bit.ly/R8hB2m

Comment: Instead of using numbered IDs, could you just rely on the class and dynamically get the index if/when needed? That obviates the need to maintain an indexed system.

Comment: no, the way it's set up right now i need the ids. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your `copyAppendQ` function with:

```
copyAppendQ.id = (copyAppendQ.id || 0)+1;
```

Then when assigning the ID:

```
id = "questioncon"+copyAppendQ.id;
```

This will ensure that you won't get the same ID twice, even if questions are deleted.

Comment: Excellent! I replaced numberOfQuestions with this in every instance and it works great! still doesn't renumber(so it the first question is Question 2 sometimes), but still, it works. Thanks, man.

Comment: You don't really need renumbering, since they will be renumbered in the `$(".question")` node list.